# Redefine input function in Python to yield a value from a predetermined list of values each time it's called

Tags: python, yield

Is there a clean "Pythonic" way to write an input-replacement function in Python that will yield a value from a predetermined list of input values each time it's called?

```
raw_data = ['8', '2', '1']
c = 0


def input():
    global c
    c += 1
    return raw_data[c - 1]


for _ in range(3):
    print(input())
```

This does and is expected to output:

```
8
2
1
```

Intuitively `yield` seems like it ought to be part of the solution but I cannot wrap my head around how to implement it as an `input` replacement.

Comment: Face palm. I knew that. Thank you!

Comment: Do you use the list for anything else?

Comment: Note that if you use `yield` instead of `return`, you don't need `c` to be global. `def input_replacement(): c = 0; while True: yield raw_data[c]; c += 1`. Perhaps the thing you were missing was the necessity to have an explicit loop in the function that uses `yield`

Comment: @Stef But then `input()` returns a generator iterator instead of a value.

Comment: @KellyBundy Indeed. So maybe it should be called `def source_of_input(): ...yield...` and then `input = source_of_input()` or something.

Comment: What is the reason for overriding *input()*?

Answer (score 3):

Two ways I've been using for that:

```
input = iter([8, 2, 1]).__next__
```

```
input = [8, 2, 1][::-1].pop
```

Of course you don't need the `[::-1]` if you're ok with writing the list backwards.

If you also need the list for something else, you can use the first solution but with the list stored in an extra variable.

---

Though the normal`input()` returns strings, so what I actually usually use for that is like this, where I copy&paste a given input data block:

```
input = iter('''\
line 1
line 2
line 3
'''.splitlines()).__next__
```

Answer (score 2):

`input` is a wrapper around reading from `sys.stdin`. You can simply replace that with a `StringIO` object instead of using whatever your process received as `sys.stdin`.

```
>>> import io, sys
>>> sys.stdin = io.StringIO("foo\nbar\nbaz\n")
>>> input()
'foo'
>>> input()
'bar'
>>> input()
'baz'
>>> input()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

You can always restore the original standard input if  and when necessary:

```
sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__
```

I don't recommend replacing replacing a built-in function with a function of a different *type*. Existing code that uses `input` will expect a return value of `str`, not the `int` your example shows. If your goal is to not patch the existing built-in, you should simply define and use your own function instead.

Comment: I was semi-surprised that `contextlib.redirect_stdin` was not provided to simplify this. https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/92178 indicates this was an intentional omission, though I leave it to the reader to track down the specific arguments against. (In summary, it's more complicated to replace an input stream correctly than it is to replace an output stream.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to the other answers. They are elegant and effective. I'm also trying to avoid exposing how IO works as much as possible so here's my take on the problem. It does require the use of `iter`, though.

```
raw_input = iter(['8', '2', '1']) # must use strings


def input():
    return next(raw_input)


for i in range(3):
    print(input())
```

And, an alternate `input`, a touch "cleaner" but a little more advanced:

```
input = raw_input.__next__
```

Thanks to [Stef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080723/stef).